# regarding heat transfer analysis over elliptical curved surface

Tags: abaqus, ansys, abaqus-odb, pyansys

It showing an error when I was trying to data check that the following part instances are not completely meshed because they contain regions with only boundary elements how to fix this problem?

I have clicked data check It is related to steady-state heat transfer problem with radiation and conduction,

Comment: Sounds like you need to correct the mesh and check the position of any boundary elements.

Comment: ok thanks,now its is showing mid edge node elements were not projected onto geometric boundary to avoid bad element formation what to do next to fix this?